# Shortest distance between point and path in OSM Magsforge (offline) map

Tags: android, openstreetmap, graphhopper, mapsforge

In an App I load an OSM / Mapsforge offline map.

How can I determine the shortest distance between a coordinate (waypoint) and the nearest path in that Mapsforge file? The info I got is the Mapsforge (offline) map.

Sorry - to repost this - I now know I have to use the "Graphhopper" tag!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With mapsforge you cannot do this. You have to use a routing library like graphhopper is one. See here how to use it: http://graphhopper.com/#developers.

But there are other offline and online routers as well. Have a look here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers and here http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing